# How to fix this error in HTML (no error shown)

Tags: javascript, html

My function `createBomb()` is not working because none of the elements are turning into bombs.

I've tried finding the error.

HTML:

```
    <div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "18">?</div>

Javascript:

function createBomb() {
    bombNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
    if (!document.getElementById(bombNum).classList.contains("bomb")) {
        document.getElementById(bombNum).classList.add("bomb");
    } else {
        createBomb();
    }
}
createBomb();
```

I expect the function `createBomb()` to make a random `div` a bomb.

Comment: Where is bombNum Element ? Please provide complete code

Comment: bombNum is the random number generated

Comment: document.getElementById(bombNum) ???? you can't add random number here there should be any html element

Comment: I solved it. I just replace .toString with the String() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace .toString() with String()

Answer (score 0):

Here i have replicated the solution for your question : https://jsfiddle.net/7xszyda1/

HTML:

```
<div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "1">?</div>
<div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "2">?</div>
<div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "3">?</div>
<div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "4">?</div>
<div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "5">?</div>
<div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "6">?</div>
```

JS:

```
function createBomb() {
    bombNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 0)) + 1;  console.log(bombNum)
    if (!document.getElementById(bombNum).classList.contains("bomb")) {
        document.getElementById(bombNum).classList.add("bomb");
        document.getElementById(bombNum).innerHTML  = "Bomb added";

    } else {
        createBomb();
    }
}
createBomb();
```